# jQuery if two statements are true, scroll to bottom of page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a bit of jquery to work that will only run if an element (shipping - which is set as a variable) has a child with a certain class AND another element contains the text "shipping". Then if that statement isn't true move onto the next one.. if that element contains the text shipping (and #shipping does NOT contain an element with a class of sp-methods) scroll down to a div.

For some reason right now if I'm on any page at all it'll scroll down to the bottom, regardless of the if statements... guh..

**jQuery**

```
if (shipping.has('.sp-methods') && ! $('#shopping-cart-totals-table:contains("shipping")').length > 0) {
    shipping.show();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
    },
    1400,
        "easeOutQuint");
    return false;
} else if ($('#shopping-cart-totals-table:contains("shipping")').length > 0) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.cart-collaterals').offset().top
    },
    1400,
        "easeOutQuint");
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

Gutted everything from my script but the following and it still scrolls to the bottom of the page on every single page regardless of if .shipping even exists or if it has .sp-methods in it or not. Not at all sure why..

```
if ($('.shipping').has('.sp-methods')) {
    shipping.show();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
    },
    1400,
        "easeOutQuint");
}
```

Here's a fiddle containing some of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/vhf5qeL4/

**This is all I'm down to, and regardless of if the page contains a element with a class of shipping, the page scrolls to the bottom. It doesn't do this if commented out. This is being tested on an Android with Chrome**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var shipping = $('.shipping');

console.log($('.shipping').has('.sp-methods'));

if ($('.shipping').has('.sp-methods')) {
$('.shipping').show();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
},
1400,
    "easeOutQuint");
} 
});
```

Comment: so test all your conditions individually from both sections of the `if` statement, outside/before the `if` statement...  ex: `console.log( shipping.has('.sp-methods') );`...  make sure they all return what you expect.  possibly consider adding a catch-all `else` to your statement...

Comment: also... for clarity, i would change this: `! $('#shopping-cart-totals-table:contains("shipping")').length > 0` because... you're saying where the length is not greater than 0.  it's more clear if you just check for when the `length==0`.

Comment: also... make sure you're using [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) correctly for your intended purpose.  it selects _all elements that contain the specified text_.

Comment: I want it to scroll down to the shopping-cart-totals-table only if it contains the word "shipping" anywhere in it or its descendants. Can contains not do that?

Comment: any live example of your problem would be appreciated, ie. using http://jsbin.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vhf5qeL4/